# list remove function on class instance in a list not working properly

Tags: python, list, class, instance

here is the code, I'm confused:

```
class Button():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

bt1 = Button('123')
bt2 = Button('3r5')
bt3 = Button('123')
bt4 = Button('1fe')
bt5 = Button('123')

bts = []

bts.extend((bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4,bt5))
bts.extend((bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4,bt5))

for bt in bts:
    if bt.text == '123':
        bts.remove(bt)

for bt in bts:
    print(bt.text)
```

And here is the results:

```
3r5
1fe
123
3r5
1fe
```

My question is, why there is one element with text '123' not been removed?

Comment: You shouldn't modify lists while iterating over them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to remove data while iterating over the list. Try a comprehension:

```
final_data = [bt for bt in bts if bt.text != "123"]
for i in final_data:
   print(i.text)
```

Output:

```
3r5
1fe
3r5
1fe
```

Comment: @Ajax1234 you haven't given the reason why its weird behaviour ,why it doesn't delete that 123

Answer (score 0):

*You're deleting the element in the list while you iterate over it. That means that the first time through the loop, i == 1, so 123 is removed from the list. Then the for loop goes to the second item in the list, which is not 3r5, but 123! Then that's removed from the list, and then the for loop goes on to the third item in the list, which is now 5. And so on. Perhaps it's easier to visualize like so, with a ^ pointing to the value of i:*

```
["123", "3r5", "123", "123", "1fe"]
   ^
That's the state of the list initially; then 1 is removed and the loop goes to the second item in the list:

["3r5", "123", "123", "1fe"]
          ^
[ "3r5", "123", "1fe"]
                  ^
so remaining elements after loop ends [ "3r5", "123"]
```

There's no good way to alter a list's length while iterating over it.